# zmq python: problem with encoding 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x80 in position 1: invalid start byte

Tags: python, sockets, utf-8, encode, pyzmq

I have a server from the training docs:

```
context = zmq.Context()
socket = context.socket(zmq.STREAM)
adrr = 'tcp://127.0.0.1:8000'
socket.bind(adrr)

try:
    message = socket.recv_string(encoding='utf-8')
    print(message)
    # if message == '1':
    #     for el in range(10):
    #         socket.send_string(1)
finally:
    socket.close()
```

and client:

```
import zmq

context = zmq.Context()

socket = context.socket(zmq.REQ)
socket.connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:8000")
try:
    socket.send_string('yes',encoding='utf-8')
    #  Get the reply.
    # while True:
    #     message = socket.recv()
    #     print('печатаю...')
    #     print(message.decode('utf-8','ignore'))
finally:
    socket.close()
```

and encoding error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\flild\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\python\Planeta_test_task\server.py", line 9, in <module>
    message = socket.recv_string(encoding='utf-8')
  File "C:\Users\flild\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\python\Planeta_test_task\lib\site-packages\zmq\sugar\socket.py", line 853, in recv_string
    return self._deserialize(msg, lambda buf: buf.decode(encoding))
  File "C:\Users\flild\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\python\Planeta_test_task\lib\site-packages\zmq\sugar\socket.py", line 752, in _deserialize
    return load(recvd)
  File "C:\Users\flild\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\python\Planeta_test_task\lib\site-packages\zmq\sugar\socket.py", line 853, in <lambda>
    return self._deserialize(msg, lambda buf: buf.decode(encoding))
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x80 in position 1: invalid start byte
```

I have already tried to change the encoding to utf-16 and others.
I don't know what to do

Comment: I'm guessing the encoding is `cp1252`.

Comment: Try printing the raw bytes of the response.